# Getting text to display after using if statements

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm on university course in Applied Computing, and I'm having a little trouble with a certain part of one of our assignments, concerning a simple program that works out how much leave an employee for a company gets. It's basic VB coding (I'm using VS2015) and the idea is that a message is displayed once a certain outcome has been ascertained using if statements.

```
'Defining the variables to be used in the program
    Dim intLength As Integer 'defining the length of service box to be an Integer, i.e. Number
    Dim strType As String = " " 'defining the type of service box to be String, i.e. Text.



    If intLength = >= 5 And strType = "Full Time" Then
        lblLeave.Text = "You are entitled to three week's leave!"
    End If


    If intLength >= 1 And intLength <= 5 And strType = "Full Time" Then
        lblLeave.Text = "You are entitled to two week's leave!"
    End If

    If intLength <= 1 And strType = "Full Time" Then
        lblLeave.Text = "You are entitled to one weeks' leave!"
    End If


    If intLength >= 0 And strType = "Part Time" Then
        lblLeave.Text = "Unfortunately only Full Time employees qualify for leave!"
    End If
```

The idea is that there are two text boxes, one to enter a number into, and the other that asks whether they are full time or part time. After entering these and clicking the confirm button, it is supposed to display the answer underneath the confirm button in a label.

I get no errors or warnings at all, but nothing happens at all! Can anyone help me out?

Comment: There's an extra = at the first if

Comment: and the strType is always " ". You don't set its value

Comment: And `intLength` is uninitialized. It will have some value, but not a predictable one.

Comment: SO is a bad place for beginners to learn. This kind of posts are usually getting many downvotes and/or being closed (you are lucky that today there haven't been too many VB.NET questions). Additionally, if you are not even able to use the debugger to fix (very) simple problems, you wouldn't learn it here. Please, try to use SO as it is expected to be used such that everyone can get some benefit. Learn somewhere else and come here to share some (relevant) knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

`strType` and `intLength` are not initialized and there's an extra `=` at the first if

Try something like this:

```
'Defining the variables to be used in the program
 Dim intLength As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtNumber.Text) 'defining the length of service box to be an Integer, i.e. Number
 Dim strType As String = txtType.Text'defining the type of service box to be String, i.e. Text.


If intLength >= 5 And strType = "Full Time" Then
    lblLeave.Text = "You are entitled to three week's leave!"
End If


If intLength >= 1 And intLength <= 5 And strType = "Full Time" Then
    lblLeave.Text = "You are entitled to two week's leave!"
End If

If intLength <= 1 And strType = "Full Time" Then
    lblLeave.Text = "You are entitled to one weeks' leave!"
End If


If intLength >= 0 And strType = "Part Time" Then
    lblLeave.Text = "Unfortunately only Full Time employees qualify for leave!"
End If
```

Comment: Remember to initialize `intLength`. Otherwise the code into all `If` statements will be skipped

Answer (score 0):

Think there may be a mistake with the parameters of the below 2 If statements.

```
If intLength >= 1 And intLength <= 5 And strType = "Full Time" Then
    lblLeave.Text = "You are entitled to two week's leave!"
End If

If intLength <= 1 And strType = "Full Time" Then
    lblLeave.Text = "You are entitled to one weeks' leave!"
End If
```

What is meant to be the outcome if `intLength = 1` and `strType = "Full Time"` because according to the above 2 If statements, it would meet requirements of both If statements.